# Access a function only once - Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Is it possible for a client that already has an ECert to access a function only once? That is, the client somehow requests an authorization (with certain information) that is verified by a third party (maybe the CA), once the permission is granted, the transaction can be made but only once.
I've read about Tcerts, but this functionality is no longer available in the 1.0+ fabric versions. I've also read about ABAC (Attribute Based Access Control) but as I understand the attributes to be verified in the chaincode are added to the entity's certificate (Ecert), not to the transaction itself that invokes the chaincode.
I hope I was clear. Thanks & Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything that you could use for this, but you could make that check part of your chaincode.

Nothing stops you from executing the function, the first time you do that you save some flag on the ledger to indicate the function has run, then if the function is called again, first you check the flag you have and if it's set to true then you don't run the function.

It's all code at the end of the day so you could implement whatever restrictions you want. it is actually better if the check is done on chaincode side, not on a client, not via a cert. Those things can be bypassed while the chaincode check will always do its job.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not exactly what I want to do, I want an identity to be able to ask permission from a trusted third party (who has several permits stored and can be obtained through an enrollment), anyway thanks your help! all information is useful for me!